# Add CDI decorator to Message Driven Bean

Tags: java, decorator, cdi, message-driven-bean

Given the following Message Driven Bean, is it possible to define a global decorator from the CDI specification to add additional behaviour?

```
@MessageDriven
public class MyMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message m) {

    }
}
```

The decorator looks like this:

```
@Decorator
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public abstract DecorateMyMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {

    @Inject
    @Delegate
    @Any
    private MessageListener delegate;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message m) {

    }
}
```

Currently, the decorator is not being executed. I have added a beans.xml file to my module.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (but don't lose hope) is no, because a `@MessageDrivenBean` is not a CDI managed bean, and [only CDI managed beans can be decorators](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#decorators).

Now, what you might be able to do (and I don't have experience doing this myself) is something like this:

- use [`@javax.annotation.Resource`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/1.3/apidocs/javax/annotation/Resource.html) to call for a `MessageListener` to be injected into a field by Java EE, not by CDI (so it will be looked up in JNDI)
- write a producer method that `@Produces` `MessageListener` instances by using a combination of that field's contents and the [`createInterceptionFactory`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#createInterceptionFactory-javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext-java.lang.Class-) method
- `@Inject` the `MessageListener` so produced wherever you want to use it

An [`InterceptionFactory`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/InterceptionFactory.html) is really the only mechanism you have to dynamically add interception (and a decorator is just a very special case of interception) to Things That Are Not CDI Managed Beans.

Finally, this will only work if you use CDI 2.0 (which is in Java EE 8 or higher).